# Windows 8.1 sound stutter

Tags: windows-8, audio

Since I installed Windows 8.1 I have had audio issues.
On any given system load the sound will occasionally stop for one second, and then just resume. This happens while watching videos, listening to music or playing games like BF4.

I installed all latest drivers, lowered the playback quality of sound to 16 bit 44100Hz but nothing seems to work.
 I am getting no help at all from Microsoft (not that I expected that) and the stuttering is driving me crazy.

My PC specs are the following:

OS: Windows 8.1 64 bit

CPU: i7-2600k

Motherboard: ASUSTeK Computer INC. P8Z68-V (LGA1155)

Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 Ti

RAM: 8GB

EDIT:

I deleted some stuff I had also installed on windows 7 (virtual machine programs) and somehow the amount of stutters significantly reduced. I now get them once in like a few hours.

Comment: open taskmgr and look if the interupt/DPC usage is high.

Comment: Do you mean this: http://puu.sh/7a5QC.png ?
I guess it is low :)

Comment: do you use the latest BIOS (http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z68V/#support)?

Comment: Yes, installed the latest bios, issue persists.

Comment: even if it shwos no DPC/ISR issues, capture a xperf trace and upload it: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140263

Comment: uploading it(~780mb) it says personal info can be in it?

Comment: uploaded: https://www.mediafire.com/?7agwdwpti47g5ga

Comment: you have indeed no DPC issues. Only regular CPU usage from chrome while playing silverlight videos.

Comment: btw, you run the WPRUI.exe and select "CPU usage" and under scenario "Audio glitches" and try to capture the issue. And you can reduce the size of the file by compressing it to 7z/RAR!!!!!!!

Comment: yeah, I forgot about compressing haha :P
And I will figure out the WPRUI.exe thingy :P

Comment: uploaded the thingy you suggested: http://www.mediafire.com/download/3g5dw4vfodcads9/RIG-KOEN.03-01-2014.11-49-15.etl.7z ;)

Comment: I cant see anything useful from it. Do you use the latest Firmware for your SSD?

Comment: I did now, had to make a bootable device :P
Well see how it goes :P

Comment: I got a stutter again, took longer then it normally did, but still happened.... I am thinking about switching back to windows 7

Comment: Sometimes it's a problem with some installed product startups. [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) might be useful for that.

Comment: How does Autoruns help me? It just shows me what programs launch when the pc starts?! Or am I missing something? Thanks for thinking with me

Comment: Did you try restarting? Sometimes the sound card can become messed up.

Comment: I had sound skipping during playback VLC media player and TV catch up. My windows media player was not playing any sound what so ever. I downloaded a codec pack which cured media player. I then opened cc cleaner and scanned the registry for errors, did all the recommended fixes and yes he VLC player now plays with no stutter as does TV catch up, the windows media player has stopped working but i'd rather have the other two.

Comment: I decided that the best fix is to re-install DirectX using an offline install.

Answer (score 1):

if you use windows 8.x you cannot use DPC Latency Checker, its outdated for that OS, try LatencyMon Instead http://www.resplendence.com/latencymon

also try downgrading the sound card and sata controller drivers to older versions and see if that helps

running msconfig and disable unnecessary software/services on startup is also a idea

Comment: I had the same problem. LatencyMon revealed that my network driver was probably the one causing the problems and I updated it and haven't had any problems since.

Comment: My results, ran it until I heard a stutter http://pastebin.com/qM5hUbLQ
Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/BoBwv7u.png

Comment: did you update nvidia driver lately? if so try going back to a older one

Comment: I have been having this issue for ~4 months, nvidia updated like 6 times in that time span....